# DC boost converter output voltage problem when load is connected

Tags: transistors, mosfet, dc, dc-dc-converter, coil

I have successfully finished one part of the DC converter. Now I came across a certain problem which I can't solve myself.

When I didn't connect a load to the output of the dc converter, there was 50V at most. But after I connected a load, even if I have my feedback code completed, it still drops to like 5 or 4V according to the load. I have searched some videos on YouTube and did exactly they did.

Here is my schematic:

[image]

I have also corrected Arduino code which was suited for ATTiny85 chip to be suitable for ATMega328P. But I'm not sure by one thing - my potentiometer is 10k and every is displayed 100k, so it means that they used this 100k value to do its purpose. Can this be the problem that I have only 10k potentiometer? If yes, should the code by fixed somehow or not?

```
#define F_CPU 8000000
int pwm = 9;
int potinput = A0;
int feedbackinput = A1;
int potinputval;
int feedbackinputval;
int pwmval;

void setup() {
  TCCR1B = TCCR1B & 0B11111000 | 0x01;
  pinMode(pwm, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(potinput, INPUT);
  pinMode(feedbackinput, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(pwm, LOW);
  pwmval = 0;
}

void loop() {
  potinputval = analogRead(potinput);
  potinputval = map(potinputval, 1023, 0, 255, 0);
  feedbackinputval = analogRead(feedbackinput);
  feedbackinputval = map(feedbackinputval, 1023, 0, 255, 0);
  while (potinputval > feedbackinputval) {
    if (pwmval == 230) {
      potinputval = analogRead(potinput);
      potinputval = map(potinputval, 1023, 0, 255, 0);
      feedbackinputval = analogRead(feedbackinput);
      feedbackinputval = map(feedbackinputval, 1023, 0, 255, 0);
    }
    else {
      pwmval = pwmval + 1;
      analogWrite(pwm, pwmval);
      potinputval = analogRead(potinput);
      potinputval = map(potinputval, 1023, 0, 255, 0);
      feedbackinputval = analogRead(feedbackinput);
      feedbackinputval = map(feedbackinputval, 1023, 0, 255, 0);
    }
  }
  while (potinputval < feedbackinputval) {
    if (pwmval == 0) {
      potinputval = analogRead(potinput);
      potinputval = map(potinputval, 1023, 0, 255, 0);
      feedbackinputval = analogRead(feedbackinput);
      feedbackinputval = map(feedbackinputval, 1023, 0, 255, 0);
    }
    else {
      pwmval = pwmval - 1;
      analogWrite(pwm, pwmval);
      potinputval = analogRead(potinput);
      potinputval = map(potinputval, 1023, 0, 255, 0);
      feedbackinputval = analogRead(feedbackinput);
      feedbackinputval = map(feedbackinputval, 1023, 0, 255, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for any sensible response :)

Comment: Your potentiometer is a voltage divider; to a first approximation it doesn't matter what resistance it has as long as its resistance is higher than your device's input resistance. You may need to increase the ADC integration time, though, if you increase its resistance.

Comment: Look at the voltage on your feedback divider.

Comment: How much load are you putting on the output? Which inductor are you using, link to the datasheet? What's your switching frequency? (Yes, I could probably figure it out from your code, but let us know so we don't have to.)

Comment: @PhilG, voltage at the feedback is somewhere around 3 Volts according to my multimeter.

Comment: @JohnD 100uH, allowing to pass at least 2A of current and frequency of PWM is around  31,25 kHz

Comment: @Hearth what do you mean? So if the resistance of the load increases, I should increase the time? It can be done with potentiometer, or no?

Comment: @MerryGR Your potentiometer is just feedback, right? I'm not talking about the load.

Comment: @Hearth my potentiometer is supposed to change the duty cycle of the signal. According to it, the voltage should change. I looked it up how a proper feedback should look like and there's no additional potentiometer included.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the potentiometer is loaded by your ADC's sample and hold capacitor, and if it can't charge that capacitor up adequately you need to increase the integration time. Other than that (as well as losses and Johnson-Nyquist noise, of course) the value of the pot doesn't matter.

Comment: @Hearth ah, can I ask what integration time is?

Comment: @MerryGR It's the amount of time the ADC takes to measure the input voltage.

Comment: @Hearth okay, so I should change the amount of time of ADC. But where can I find it in my code? Does it stand for Analog-to-Digital Converter?

Comment: So your highest input power is 10W (5V x the 2A your inductor can handle).  Assuming maybe 80% efficiency you can get 8W out.  At 50V 8W is 160mA, which is roughly the maximum output current you can expect.  Again, how much load are you putting on the output?

Comment: @MerryGR Also your current ripple will be pretty high, around 1.44A.  So your output current will be even more limited, maybe to around 120mA if that 2A rating is a saturation current limit.  You could maybe get more if the 2A rating is the thermal limit and the sat current is higher.

Comment: @JohnD I put there 220 Ohm resistor. But the code should be designed to automatically support any voltage up to 50V no matter which load value I'm using. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @MerryGR Yes, you are missing something.  The code can't deliver energy from the input to the output, only your inductor can do that.  And the inductor is limited in how much energy it can deliver per switching period.  If "no matter which load" was true, you could power a city with it, right? So understanding the limitations is important.  Try a 500 Ohm resistor and see if that works.

Comment: @JohnD also one thing I forgot to mention, I tried like 2,000 Ohm resistor back then, and I could climb up to 13V...

Comment: @MerryGR OK, then you have another issue besides output current.

Comment: @JohnD well, I got lost.. any other advice you could give me?

Comment: @MerryGR Are you really using a 2SK3067 FET? It has 4 Ohms RDSon, and a max threshold of 4V so not suitable for logic level drive OR a 5V boost with 2A input current.  Find a 100V FET with low RDSon specified for 4.5V gate operation: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDMC86102LZ-D.PDF

Comment: @JohnD oh hell, is this the reason why this is happening? I should pay attention more to the datasheets.. didn't even notice that.

Comment: Are you sure the PWM frequency is 31kHz? the analogwrite library is a few hundred Hz for most boards.  The reason I mentioned the divider is that it's putting 8/9 times the measured voltage at the analog input, so once you get above 5.6V the ADC maxes out and you lose any regulation.

Comment: I'm using ATMega328P and set the frequency of pin 9 to 31kHz using this website
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=16612#msg121031

and added this line to my code: 
TCCR1B = TCCR1B & 0b11111000 | 0x01;

Comment: @PhilG you think there's a problem with that?